# Google Play In-App-Billing V3 : confirm transaction

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

Data flow for a purchase request with Google In-App-Billing V2 is :

[image: Google In-App-Billing V2]

The last part (**CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS**)  allows developers to confirm that the item was successfully delivered to the user.

in V3, transaction is confirmed as soon as "**onActivityResult()**" is called. My question is : how to "cancel" a transaction when error/exception occurs ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API to cancel a purchase through the Google Wallet Merchant. You have to do it manually.

Comment: Thank you. How can I handle crashes ? (User will be debited but item won't be delivered). Should I call the consumePurchase() method in a try/catch ? Thank you

Comment: Item will be stored in the lAB inventory until you consume it. Even if your app would crash during purchase the item should be delivered and available in the inventory.